# Can JUnit's timeout message be controlled?

Tags: java, build, junit

Suppose I have a JUnit unit test that has two parts to it and I don't want to separate the parts into separate [`@Test`](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Test.html) methods. Suppose also that I want a [`timeout`](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Test.html#timeout%28%29) parameter for the test.

How can I change/intercept/control the timeout assertion failure message to indicate which part of the test timed out?

Here's an attempt that does not work:

```
@Test(timeout = 1000)
public void test() {
    try {
        // part one of the test
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        Assert.fail("Part one failed");
    }

    try {
        // part two of the test
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        Assert.fail("Part two failed");
    }
}
```

Comment: Can it not be broken up into two separate tests? Or have one test with only one part, and one test with both?

Comment: @Apropos Of course that can be done as a workaround, but I want to know if there's a direct way to do it

Comment: Not by just using `timeout` and with the default test runner. You could write your own runner and have the test set a flag before it enters each block, and then your runner reads out the right message when it fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just reading up on the documentation, no. The timeout automatically fails the test. This isn't throwing an exception -- it's done by the test runner. It's possible that you could write your own test runner, but you're still going to have troubles finding out where it failed. I would suggest structuring your test differently. Possibly have your own timer that just fails the test.

Answer (score 1):

JUnit's timeout feature is rather limited as you've found out. For timing related tests that require a little more features I've used [awaitility](https://code.google.com/p/awaitility/wiki/Usage). You can use "named await" to customize the message:

```
with().pollInterval(ONE_HUNDERED_MILLISECONDS)
    .and().with().pollDelay(20, MILLISECONDS)
    .await("customer registration").until(
            costumerStatus(), equalTo(REGISTERED)
);
```